# Multiple Bind and base DNs in ldap.conf

Tags: linux, ldap

I have multiple LDAP servers and different user groups in each. I want to authenticate using both LDAP servers which have different base DNs.

Is it possible to put in multiple bind and base DN values in ldap.conf?

Answer (score 1):

No. At best, you could split off authentication to one server and your NSS lookups for users and groups to another server.

The only way to have a "meta database" that consolidates the information of both is to actually maintain one. You must sync data from one server to the other, or set up a third server that replicates the necessary trees from the two other servers.

Comment: Hi @andrew-b. How do you split off authentication and the NSS lookups. I do not quite get the picture.

Comment: @Carlo That's a different question than the one you were asking and the answer is not simple. Please submit a new question.

Comment: Hi @Andrew. I've already created a question and here is the link: http://serverfault.com/questions/521800/split-authentication-and-nss-lookups-for-users-and-groups-to-different-servers

Thank you very much for the response.