# Split authentication and NSS lookups for users and groups to different servers

Tags: linux, ldap, openldap

I've asked this question previously: [Multiple Bind and base DNs in ldap.conf](https://serverfault.com/questions/521421/multiple-bind-and-base-dns-in-ldap-conf/521424)

Since that previous question was answered in the negative, I'm looking for other options such as splitting authentication and NSS lookups (as suggested in the answer provided in the link above).

How is authentication and NSS lookups split into different servers?

Comment: Suggestion: If a question requires reading another question for background information, it's less likely to be answered. Try to keep questions self-contained. (though it's okay to link to them)

Answer (score 0):

It's tricky. You need a PAM module that performs LDAP authentication, but *doesn't* use the same configuration as your LDAP plugin for NSS. This is problematic because most distros assume you're using an integrated LDAP solution.

- PADL's `pam_ldap` module looks like it can be configured to use a different configuration file than the one used by PADL's LDAP plugin for NSS.

  - Be advised that PADL's implementation of LDAP for NSS does not involve a daemon like `nscld` and is considered inferior for that reason.
  - If your distro allows you to use nslcd and PADL's pam_ldap side by side, you can try that. (not likely) The packages are usually mutually exclusive because they provide similar functionality. Unless the NSS plugin is packaged separately, there will be a file conflict. (`libnss_ldap.so`)
- Take a look at `pam_sssd`, if your distro supplies it. I *think* it might be possible to use these side by side, but it relies upon `sssd` and I haven't set that up before.
- Custom compile a pam_ldap implementation and configure it to use a separate configuration file. You're on your own for this. Of note, PADL's pam_ldap looks like it can be built separately from its NSS library.
- If you have a Kerberos implementation (i.e. Active Directory), you can use `pam_krb5.so` for authentication and point NSS at LDAP...but be warned that Kerberos requires its own subset of knowledge to configure correctly.

No matter what, this is going to be time consuming. You may be better off replicating the necessary data between your two LDAP servers so that you can point your server at a single one.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much for the response! You've been really helpful.